# What is the difference between "withZone()" and "toDateTime()" methods of joda DateTime

Tags: datetime, timezone, jodatime

What is the difference between these two DateTime's methods?

DateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone zone)

DateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone zone)

??

They both seem to load the timezone, without touching the millis of the DateTime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe they are identical.  They perform the same function anyway.  They appear to be implemented separately, rather than having one call the other.  I'm unsure why.

The only difference I can see is that `toDateTime` *must* be implemented, because it is defined in `AbstractInstant`, and `DateTime` extends `AbstractInstant`.

Answer (score 0):

toDateTime may return same object if time zone is the same, withZone always makes a copy